# javascript in link button with inner method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, quotes

I have OnClientClick which is asking if user sure to do this in language that users choice. but It doesn't work because of too many quotes mixes. any one knows how to do this?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Sil" CssClass="red" OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" CommandArgument='<%# Item.UId %>' 
OnClientClick='<%= "return confirm('" + MULTILANGG("Areyousureyouwanttodeletethis") +"')"%>'><i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: When you said "too many quotes mixed" is because MULTILANGG("Areyousureyouwanttodeletethis") also have quotes?

Comment: yes exactly what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your string outside, in a regular script tag - then you wouldn't need any server code in your tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _areYouSure = "<%= MULTILANGG("Areyousureyouwanttodeletethis") %>";
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ... OnClientClick="return confirm(_areYouSure);" ...></asp:LinkButton>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a pattern you may like better - since you've got some kind of translation file, you can keep things organized by storing a single object containing all translations, defined in javascript at the top of your page. They'd be organized, in a single place, and you could then use them anywhere in your javascript.

```
var _resources = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    areYouSureDelete = MULTILANGG("Areyousureyouwanttodeletethis"),
    welcome = MULTILANGG("Welcome"),
    submit = MULTILANGG("Submit"),
    cancel = MULTILANGG("Cancel")
}) %>;

<asp:LinkButton ... OnClientClick="return confirm(_resources.areYouSureDelete);" ...></asp:LinkButton>
```

Note that the string is built in C#, so all of the escaping is taken care of, and you'll end up with a valid javascript object.

Comment: I know I can do that which I don't prefer, if possible.

Comment: Edited with a suggestion if you're looking to keep things a little more organized than just a single variable floating around out there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to split this out into its own js function

function confirmDelete() {
      return confirm('<%=MULTILANGG("Areyousureyouwanttodeletethis")%>')
   }

then

```
OnClientClick="confirmDelete()"
```

Comment: I know I can do that which I don't prefer, if possible.

Comment: The cleaner approach IMO is to dump all server side data needed to a JSON packet, and read that from the javascript as a var.  It can either be src'd (like jsonp) or dropped in the page as a js variable.  It's better to minimize the surface area where two languages intermingle I think.

Answer (score 0):

You're close!  Try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Sil" CssClass="red" 
    OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" CommandArgument='<%# Item.UId %>' 
    OnClientClick="return confirm('<%= MULTILANGG("Areyousureyouwanttodeletethis") %>')">
    <i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Got this error; Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.